# Getting the Key (text) of a selected option in a html5 select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html

I am playing around with a select field. I want to access the key(displayed text) of it. This is currently working, but feels kind of stupid.

```
<select onChange={
  (e) => {
    console.log('e.target', e.target);
    onChangeEvent(e.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text, e.target.value);
}}>
  ...
</select>
```

Is there something better for

> e.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text

without using jQuery, additional modules...

Comment: you could use `e.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].text` slightly shorter

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about IE:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.select')

select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const selected = e.target.selectedOptions[0]
  console.log(selected.text, selected.value)
})
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have no Idea why this works. But nice 1. is there a shorter version with IE support?